# How to combine two differente templates in one common app in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to create different templates, but both of them share almost the same attributes. For example, both the blog page and the movie page have the model 'Post' that allows users to add new Articles/Movies to the Website.

Also, I assume that the 'Movie - Post' model would need different fields than the 'Article - Post' model, but they still share many of them.

Someone can help me how to implement that out?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways to do this.

**1. Make an outer file and insert all your code into the inner file. This uses extends.**

The outer file, base.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<p> You can also put anything else you want on every page here.</p>
    <main role="main" class="container">
     {% block content %}
     {% endblock %}
        </main>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The inner file, page.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<p>This is the stuff you want to be unique to the page. </p>
{% endblock %}
```

The disadvantage of this method is that you are essentially putting one page inside another and it is a little less flexible.

**2. Include the chunk of code inside an HTML file. This uses include.**

The page you want to add the header to, page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
</head>


<style>
body { padding-top: 70px;
        font-family: Poppins;
     }

</style>
<body>
    {% include "header.html" %}

    <main role="main" class="container">
<p> Whatever you want on your page</p>

        </main>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The actual code for your header, header.html

```
<div class="header">
  <p>My supercool header</p>
</div>
```

Include will insert that block of HTML code right where you put the include statement.

Comment: See my other answer regarding that. If these answers suit your needs, click the checkmark to the left of one so that the community knows that your issues are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the models with common elements, you can do something like this:

```
from django.db import models

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
#common fields go here
    post = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Blog(CommonInfo):
#fields unique to blog go here
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class Movie(CommonInfo):
#fields unique to movie go here
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```